# javascript step condition not working in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using HTML Tag in asp.net for multi step Progress bar Purpose. but script not working in my application please provide me a solution for this

My Asp.net code is-

```
    <div class="progress" runat="server">

        <div class="progress-track" runat="server" ></div>
        <div id="step1" class="progress-step" runat="server"   >
           Step1
        </div>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    </div>
     

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Next" type="button" OnClientClick="return next();" onClick="NextStep" />
```

and javascript is-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    let step = 'step1';
    const step1 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_step1');
    const step2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_step2');
    const step3 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_step3');

    function next(step) {
        if (step === 'step1') {
            step = 'step2';
            step1.classList.remove("is-active");
            step1.classList.add("is-complete");
            step2.classList.add("is-active");

        .
        .
        .
        } else if (step === 'complete') {
            step = 'step1';
            step3.classList.remove("is-complete");
            step2.classList.remove("is-complete");
            step1.classList.remove("is-complete");
            step1.classList.add("is-active");
        }
    }
</script>
```

step process not working

Answer (score 1):

This is because you create a postback to the server and the server doesn't care about client-side changes and renders the old state again.

Easiest solution would be to convert your javascript to c# code and do this in code behind as I assume, you doing other server-side stuff in the button-handler also.